# Javascript date time comparison returns false but branch stmt still executed

Tags: javascript

I am confused with this Javascript behaviour. Check this code.

```
var NoOfMonthsElapsed = 6; //Should be >= 1 and <= 12
var MsgURL = "about:blank";
var PopupTitle = "ContactInfoUpdate";
var OptionString = "height=165,width=400,menubar=0,toolbar=0,location=1,status=0,resizable=0,status=0,HAlign=center,top=300";

var lastUpdatedDate = crmForm.all.dxb_lastcontactinfoupdatedon.DataValue; //Reads a field with date value = 01 Jan 2010
if (lastUpdatedDate)
{
  var month = lastUpdatedDate.getMonth();
  var year  = lastUpdatedDate.getYear();
  var date  = lastUpdatedDate.getDate();

  month = month + NoOfMonthsElapsed;
  year  = year  + parseInt(month / 11);
  month = (month % 11);

  var today = new Date();
  var showPopupAfterDate = new Date();

  showPopupAfterDate.setYear(year);
  showPopupAfterDate.setMonth(month);

  var alertMsg  = "LastUpdatedDate          = "+ lastUpdatedDate + "\n"
  var alertMsg += "Today                    = "+ today + "\n"
  var alertMsg += "PopupAfterDate           = "+ showPopupAfterDate + "\n"
  var alertMsg += "Today>showPopupAfterDate = "+ (today>showPopupAfterDate) + "\n"

  alert(alertMsg);

  if (today>showPopupAfterDate); 
  {
    window.open(MsgURL, PopupTitle, OptionString);
  }
}
else 
{
  window.open(MsgURL, PopupTitle, OptionString);
}




//
// It displays the following output
//
LastUpdatedDate          = Wed May 18 20:56:00 UTC+0400 2011
Today                    = Fri May 18 20:23:49 UTC+0400 2011
PopupAfterDate           = Fri Nov 18 20:23:49 UTC+0400 2011
Today>showPopupAfterDate = false
```

Why today is shown as Fri May 18 2011... though May 18 2011 is Wed
Why PopupAfterDate is shown as Fri Nov 18 2011...
And Even though the dates comparission returns false; The window.open still get executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue:

```
  if (today>showPopupAfterDate) //<-- remove the `;`
  {
    window.open(MsgURL, PopupTitle, OptionString);
  }
```

Your code is running the if, **stopping**, then doing the next statement which is the `window.open`

Comment: Ouch... that hurts... How could I missed that... damn

Comment: SMKamran, it happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 2):

Your trailing semicolon closes the `if` statement:

```
if (today>showPopupAfterDate);
// --------------------------^
```

Comment: It's not just "not needed"; it's broken.

Comment: sorry for my bad english, i mean what you mean, see the second part of my comment...

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Your `{` and `}` are messy and</strike> you have a `;` at the wrong place.

```
if (lastUpdatedDate) {   
    ....
    if (today>showPopupAfterDate)    { // notice I removed ;
        window.open(MsgURL, PopupTitle, OptionString);   
    } 
} else  {
   window.open(MsgURL, PopupTitle, OptionString); 
}
```

Comment: i agree with the `;`, but the placing of the `{  }` is preference

Comment: @Neal: In this case, it directly led to this bug. What does that tell you?

Comment: @Tomalak, how did the `{ }` lead to it?

Comment: @Neal: From a distance, `if (...) ; {` looks very wrong. `if (...) ;` does not.

Comment: @Tomalak, that may be, but i still believe `{  }` placement is a preference

Comment: @Neal: It's definitely a preference. A bad one. :)